# Using AppleScript to Enable Snow Leopard's Text Replacement Feature

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, text-editors, applescript, quicksilver, rememberthemilk

I currently use Quicksilver with a Plugin and Trigger in concert with Snow Leopard's text replacement feature (for frequently-used combinations of hashtags, due dates and other parameters) to quickly send tasks to Remember The Milk (http://www.rememberthemilk.com).

Unfortunately, I have to click "Text Replacement" from the right-click menu of the text entry field in order to use that feature.  I'm suspecting that I can add some AppleScript to the Trigger as a work-around to do that automatically.  If so, what would be the best way to go about this?  Would I need to use GUI scripting?

Answer (score 0):

Assign a keyboard shortcut to the menu item *Edit » Substitutions » Text Replacement* in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Application Shortcuts*.

[image]
[image]
[image]

If you only want this to work in Safari, restrict the *Application* setting accordingly.

---

Once this is done, you can simply use the following AppleScript to trigger it programmatically:

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "r" using {shift down, control down}
```

Of course, this depends on the shortcut you define.

Comment: Thanks for the insight but it it doesn't work for Quicksilver as the Text Replacement menu bar item does not seem to exist within that application.  The option only appears in its context menu.