# Switch between Google Chrome Tabs using AppleScript

Tags: macos, google-chrome, applescript

I was hoping that the following code would do the job, but no cigar:

```
--Only the window is brought into focus
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate tab 1 of window 1
end tell
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Google Chrome is, in fact, scriptable.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to set active tab index of first window to 3
```

Works like a charm for version 10.0.648.204.

---

While it would be nice to do something like the following:

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to set active tab of first window 
    to first tab of the first window whose title is "Super User"
```

It's not possible, since `active tab` is a read-only property. You'd need to loop over all a window's tabs to find the index of the one you want by querying each tab's title, and then set the `active tab index`:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set i to 0
    repeat with t in (tabs of (first window whose index is 1))
        set i to i + 1
        if title of t is "Super User" then
            set (active tab index of (first window whose index is 1)) to i
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: +1... "You'd need to loop over all a window's tabs..." yep, that's called programming... to not be embarrassed to write long, ugly code as long as there's no other way through it :)

Comment: @Yar It *is* inconvenient though, especially since AppleScript apparently tries to be usable by people who are not programmers. But since the user didn't want that anyway, I didn't write it ;-)

Comment: I don't actually know Applescript, but if this part is valid `whose title is "Super User"` then I'd think that you could get the tab index directly from, um, the "first window"... no way?

Comment: @Yar Don't know what you mean. There's no way to get a tab's `index`, and `active tab` is read-only. The first snippet works, which is what the user wanted. I added to my post how you'd do the second example so it works.

Comment: @Daniel Beck, understood, thanks. It's surprising that these basic things are not accounted for. Is this the API for Chrome (?) or Applescript that is to blame (so to speak)?

Comment: @Yar This particular issue is the API provided by the Chrome devs. It might be related to that being a major pain to do, but I have never had to implement AppleScript support myself, so I'm not qualified to judge.

Comment: @Daniel Beck Sorry for my failure to respond sooner.  The code you mentioned indeed works.  Now I've got to deal with it sometimes failing to create a new window for the tabs when I ask it to, but that's probably a bug on their end.

Comment: You can actually change to a tab by its name in a single event descriptor (at least in 14.0): `tell app "Google Chrome" to tell window 1 to set active tab index to id of tab 1 where title is "Google"`

Comment: This no longer works. Now it returns an error. `Google Chrome got an error: Can’t get window 1 whose index = 1. Invalid index.`

Answer (score 4):

I just finished this amazing script, which required a lot of googling and guessing, but it works.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    repeat with w in (windows)
        set j to 0
        repeat with t in (tabs of w)
            set j to j + 1
            if title of t contains "Workflowy" then
                set (active tab index of w) to j
                set index of w to 1
                tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
                    perform action "AXRaise" of window 1 -- `set index` doesn't always raise the window
                end tell
                return
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

The `do shell script` is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34375804/8047): it gets the Window to accept keystrokes.

You can use [FastScripts](https://red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) to make this work (and there are many other methods, too)

Comment: This works very well. And thankfully with Google Chrome, having duplicate pages in the browser does not cause an error (unlike Safari).

Comment: After using this a bit, I noticed the `i` variable doesn't seem to be doing anything. Unless I'm missing something, the script seems to work the same without it.

Comment: Also, it would probably be more informative to have more descriptive variable names. Something like `the_window` for `w` and `the_tab` for `t` and `tab_index` for `j` would probably go a long way in helping others better understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to write a script to pause and play Netflix, and the code provided above was a good framework for searching through the tabs.
     "whose index is 1" kept throwing compiler errors on my Mac Mini 10.8.3, so, based on code from http://en.blog.guylhem.net/post/9835498027/google-chrome-next-tab-in-applescript , I just removed the reference entirely (which worked for my purposes)

The script basically activates the browser window, goes through tabs until it finds one titled "Netflix", and sends it key code 49 (spacebar).

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    set i to 0
    repeat with t in (tabs of (first window))
        set i to i + 1
        if title of t is "Netflix" then
            set (active tab index of (first window)) to i
        end if
    end repeat
    tell application "System Events" to key code 49
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome isn't scriptable (that is, it doesn't understand Apple Events).  You can script it the hard way using the Accessibility API (which you need to turn on in System Preferences > System > Universal Access; see the "Enable access for assistive devices" checkbox at the bottom); this is done via the Processes suite of [System Events](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/as_related_apps.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001570-1149074-BAJEIHJA).  Unfortunately, this is extremely painful in the general case, but something like

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Google Chrome"
        click tab 1 of window 1
    end tell
end tell
```

might suffice.  If it doesn't, then you'll need to explicitly dig the tab element out of the widget tree; Apple has some [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html) that can help you find UI elements.

Comment: Although I didn't find it applicable for this question I found this info. to be quite useful.  It almost helped me figure out the answer to this question!: http://superuser.com/questions/237758/using-applescript-to-enable-snow-leopards-text-replacement-feature.  Unfortunately, in that case the AppleScript Editor seemed to refuse to acknowledge the existence of the scroll area containing my desired UI element that UIElement Inspector told me to look for.