# any way to assign hotkeys to open minimized windows?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, dock, window-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cycling through minimized windows](https://superuser.com/questions/26770/cycling-through-minimized-windows)

I usually have 3-4 firefox windows, 1 macvim and adium in OSX 10.7. I like to keep only one or two windows open at a time with the rest minimized to the dock. I'm wondering if there's a way for me to be able to quickly open a minimized window using a shortcut key. I'd love to be able to assign these windows numbers and be able to open them with a shortcut. Any ideas?

Comment: You could use AppleScripts to for example click the first item on the right side of the Dock. See [Keyboard shortcut to unhide or unminimize a window in OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/196141/keyboard-shortcut-to-unhide-or-unminimize-a-window-in-os-x/252145#252145).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no built-in way to do this.

You might want to look into macro software such as Keyboard Maestro. It allows you to switch to a certain application by hotkey and then you can select from the open windows.

Once you install Keyboard Maestro, the built-in hotkey for cycling between windows of the same application is Ctrl-Tab.

Other than that you might want to create Apple Scripts that activate a certain window and then assign hotkeys to the apple script using Keyboard Maestro. For ideas on Apple Script, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655502/applescript-activate-window-of-a-non-scriptable-application

There appears a way to switch to a certain tab in Chrome, Firefox should not be any different: [Switch between Google Chrome Tabs using AppleScript](https://superuser.com/questions/263198/switch-between-google-chrome-tabs-using-applescript)

Alternatives to KM are iKey, QuicKeys and there must be others. (KM is the one I use for Mac macros, I have no financial interest in it.)